# Before calling `createReduxContainer`, please call `createReactNavigationReduxMiddleware`, so that we know when to trigger your listener

Tags: react-native, redux

I am not able to solve the error can you please help

Comment: you should always post your code

Comment: Here is the link of the code https://next.plnkr.co/edit/github:plnkr/starters/v1.3.6/templates/react?open=Hello.js&deferRun=1